# Accidentally deleted server.crt from bitnami

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, bitnami

I Accidentally deleted server.crt from /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/. I am unable to open my website since then. How would I regenerate it or get it back?

Comment: Post relevant httpd.conf code that references that cert.

Comment: You took backups of your server, right? Restore from backup. If not, this is what happens when you don't backup important things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can generate new certificates by running these commands:

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key 2048
sudo openssl req -new -key /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key -out /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/cert.csr
sudo openssl x509 -in /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/cert.csr -out /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.crt -req -signkey /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server.key -days 365
sudo chmod 600 /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/server*
```

They will generate new self-signed certificate files. In case you bought a valid certificate from a Certificate Authority, you only need to copy the files to the apache2/conf folder again.

Restart Apache to load this new certificate

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

More information about this in our documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/#how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate